# duplicate error

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using the following module to generate a unique id. But everyday it throws `IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '122830001' for key 'PRIMARY'")` for the first loanid.

I'm unable to find the reason for the problem. Please help?

```
def generate_loanid(leadid='0', counter=0):
    """ Locks the customer_loanid table retrieves maximum loanid from it.
        Generates a new loanid and puts it back in the table.
        Returns the new loanid.
    """
    def gen_id(max_loanid=0, count=0):
        """
        Increments the counter if an id exists for the day.
        Else resets the counter and creates a fresh one.
        """
        timestamp_now = time.localtime()
        if max_loanid:
            logger.debug("""Current Maximum Loan id :
                        (Year(YY)+Julian Day(DDD)+Counter(CCCC) %d,
                        Current timestamp : %s""" %(max_loanid, timestamp_now))
            julian_day = (max_loanid/10000) % 1000
            if julian_day == timestamp_now[7]:
                count = max_loanid % 10000
        return (str(timestamp_now[0])[2:] +
                str(timestamp_now[7]).rjust(3, '0') +
                str(count+1).rjust(4, '0')
                )

    logger.debug("Leadid:%s - Counter:%s"%(leadid, counter))
    db_obj = dbLis(pooling=False)
    try:
        try:
            db_obj.query("lock tables customer_loanid write")
            max_loanid = db_obj.query("select max(loanid) as loanid from customer_loanid")
            curr_loanid = gen_id(max_loanid = max_loanid.__len__() and max_loanid[0].loanid)
            db_obj.insert('customer_loanid', loanid=curr_loanid)
        except (MySQLdb.IntegrityError,MySQLdb.OperationalError):
            logger.warning(traceback.format_exc())
            #There is no logical backing for this piece of code.
            if counter < 3:
                db_obj.query("unlock tables")
                return generate_loanid(counter=counter+1)
            else:
                raise
    finally:
        try:
            db_obj.query("unlock tables")
            logger.debug("Unlocked All Tables")
            db_obj.ctx.db.close()
        except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
            logger.info("Table unlocked already")
            logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
    logger.info("Generated Loanid : %s"%(curr_loanid))
    return curr_loanid
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_loanid` (
  `loanid` int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`loanid`)
)
```

Comment: Why are you using `max_loanid.__len__()` instead of `len(max_loanid)`?

Comment: Please provide the complete code as well as the table structure. We do not know which is your `PRIMARY` key. And this code only has a `SELECT` query. A Duplicate error can only occur from modifying queries such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` etc.

Comment: The `IntegretyError` are because you are trying to save something with an id (122830001) that already exists. What does your table-structure look like?

Comment: @MartijnPieters no intention behind using __len__().is that cause problem?

Comment: @shiva: I doubt it, but calling special methods directly is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @glglgl db_obj.insert('customer_loanid', loanid=curr_loanid)
 inser query is there.i updated table structure;

Comment: @mariusnn i updated table structure

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks.i ll change it to len()

Comment: Why do you need such a complex way of calculating the LoanID anyway? Would not an id with `AUTO_INCREMENT` do the trick?

Comment: @mariusnn this code existed even before i join.... I just debugging it for this error.

Comment: @shiva Seems like the problem is that the counter working its way to "next available id" creates an "overflow" (handled in the code by `count = max_loanid % 10000`). This means if the count of IDs on a given day exceeds 10000, the ID returned are stripped (count of 10001 would give a count of 1), and hence a collision is generated.

Comment: @mariusnn i know that.But this loanid logic used for long time.i can't afford to change the logic as it will affect the historic data.

Comment: @mariusnn good catch.but the error occurs usually early in the day(from 12 - 1 a.m) and daily loanid count never exceed 10000.

Comment: If you cannot change things, you'll be stuck with the problem. As it is written now, there is a limit of 10000 IDs per day. You either change logic to accomodate for this or you let the program suffer...

Comment: The table-locks should handle the race-conditions which would otherwise be a feasible explanation for what you are experiencing, but my experience here is very limited.

Comment: You could catch the error and then "retry" a few times before giving up? The recalculation should accomodate for the already existing id.

Comment: @mariusnn i am trying for 3 times before giving up

Comment: I posted a suggested approach with some guidelines for my thinking. Your code is quite messy, so I did not place it into that context as I would suggest you do some cleanup anyway.

Comment: All boiling down to: 
    sql = "INSERT INTO customer_loanid (SELECT "+min_id_of_day+" + count(*) FROM customer_loanid WHERE loanid LIKE '"+day_part_of_id%+"'"

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all in one single query:

```
timestamp_now = time.localtime()
day_part_of_id = str(timestamp_now[0])[2:] + str(timestamp_now[7]).rjust(3, '0')
min_id_of_day = day_part_of_id + '0001'

sql = "INSERT INTO customer_loanid (SELECT "+min_id_of_day+" + count(*) FROM customer_loanid WHERE loanid LIKE '"+day_part_of_id+"%'"
```

Comment: min_id_of_day = day_part_of_id + '0001'
will throw duplicate error

Comment: But in the query the ID will add to that the number of already excisting IDs with that prefix (Treated as a number). Henvce the ID will be xxxxx0004 when there are already three ids with the same prefix in the table.